# Dialog dismiss not working inside adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a modal(dialog) with a edit text inside and a send button, what i'm trying to do is simply send the content inside the edit text when the button is clicked, the thing is, sending the content is working, but when i call `mydialog.dismiss();` it doesn't work. It is using an instance of another class to call a method retrofit, and inside the "done" and "not done" buttons i have the "enviar"(send) button which is the one i'm trying to close the modal with.

Here is the adapter code:

```
public TasksAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @SuppressLint("SupportAnnotationUsage") @LayoutRes ArrayList<Tasks> list){
    super(context, 0, list);
    sContext = context;
    taskData = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){

    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(sContext).inflate(R.layout.item_tasks, parent,false);

    final Tasks presenteTask = taskData.get(position);

    TextView taskTitle = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tasksTitle);
    taskTitle.setText(presenteTask.getTitle());

    EditText taskColor = (EditText) listItem.findViewById(R.id.taskColor);
    if(presenteTask.getHexaColor().isEmpty()){
        HexaColor = "#FFFFFF";
    }
    else{
        HexaColor = presenteTask.getHexaColor();
        taskColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(HexaColor));
    }

    TextView taskTime = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.taskTime);
    taskTime.setText(presenteTask.getTimeStart().toString().substring(0,5));

    tasksModal = new Dialog(sContext);
    tasksModal.setCancelable(false);
    tasksModal.setContentView(R.layout.modal_tasksdone);
    tasksModal.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    final EditText comentarios = (EditText) tasksModal.findViewById(R.id.edtComentario);
    final Calendario calendario = new Calendario();

    Button done = (Button) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tasksDone);
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            yorn = true;
            tarefaId = presenteTask.getTaskId();
            data = presenteTask.getDataTask();
            hora = String.valueOf(presenteTask.getTimeStart());

            tasksModal.findViewById(R.id.btnSend).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    comentario = comentarios.getText().toString();
                    if(comentario.equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(sContext,"Por favor digite um comentário.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        tasksModal.dismiss();
                    }
                    else{
                        calendario.retrofitDoneTasks(tarefaId, comentario, data, hora, yorn, tarefaRealizadaId);
                        tasksModal.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });

            tasksModal.show();
        }
    });

    Button notDone = (Button) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tasksNotDone);
    notDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            yorn = false;
            tarefaId = presenteTask.getTaskId();
            data = presenteTask.getDataTask();
            hora = String.valueOf(presenteTask.getTimeStart());

            tasksModal.findViewById(R.id.btnSend).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    comentario = comentarios.getEditableText().toString();
                    if(comentario.equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(sContext,"Por favor digite um comentário.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        tasksModal.dismiss();
                    }
                    else{
                        calendario.retrofitDoneTasks(tarefaId, comentario, data, hora, yorn, tarefaRealizadaId);
                        tasksModal.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });

            tasksModal.show();
        }
    });

    return listItem;
}
```

}

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried debugging? your tasksModal.dismiss(); will only work when your enviar button is clicked and the else part is executed. Suggest you to use your dismiss dialog in all possibilities. let me know if your tasksModal.dismiss() is executed and still doesnt work

Comment: @PraveenGM i've tried debugging it, and it does execute the else part, thats why i'm finding all this so weird.

Comment: For future references, it is better if you translate the messages and comments in the code as well, so people trying to help can have a better context and know what's happening.

Comment: @RicardoA. Will do Ricardo, thank you for the advice! :D

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly** you have to make your dialog un-cancelable, so that outside click doesn't dismiss it using `tasksModal.setCancelable(false);`

**Secondly** no need to repeat code to create dialog inside `done/undone` button click. So, remove it and move it to `TasksAdapter` constructor.

**Thirdly** You are not dismissing your dialog inside `done` button click. So, add this `tasksModal.dismiss();`

Check and try with below code:

```
EditText comentarios;
Calendario calendario;

public TasksAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @SuppressLint("SupportAnnotationUsage") @LayoutRes ArrayList<Tasks> list){
    super(context, 0, list);
    sContext = context;
    taskData = list;
    tasksModal = new Dialog(sContext);
    tasksModal.setCancelable(false); //make it un cancelable
    tasksModal.setContentView(R.layout.modal_tasksdone);
    tasksModal.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    comentarios = (EditText) tasksModal.findViewById(R.id.edtComentario);
    calendario = new Calendario();
}
-------------------------------------------------------------
Button done = (Button) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tasksDone);
done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        comentarios.setText("");
        yorn = true;
        tarefaId = presenteTask.getTaskId();
        data = presenteTask.getDataTask();
        hora = String.valueOf(presenteTask.getTimeStart());

        tasksModal.findViewById(R.id.btnSend).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                comentario = comentarios.getEditableText().toString();
                if(!comentario.equals("")){
                    tasksModal.dismiss(); //dismiss here
                    calendario.retrofitDoneTasks(tarefaId, comentario, data, hora, yorn, tarefaRealizadaId);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(sContext,"Por favor digite um comentário.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        tasksModal.show();
    }
});

Button notDone = (Button) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tasksNotDone);
notDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        comentarios.setText("");
        yorn = false;
        tarefaId = presenteTask.getTaskId();
        data = presenteTask.getDataTask();
        hora = String.valueOf(presenteTask.getTimeStart());

        tasksModal.findViewById(R.id.btnSend).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                comentario = comentarios.getEditableText().toString();
                if(comentario.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(sContext,"Por favor digite um comentário.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    tasksModal.dismiss();
                    calendario.retrofitDoneTasks(tarefaId, comentario, data, hora, yorn, tarefaRealizadaId);
                }
            }
        });

        tasksModal.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This way, the OnClickListener from the enviar button we put a "final" on is not called, i don't know why either.

Comment: try with updated answer, I have tried in my side and found ok

Comment: @RicardoA. Actually i am updating the description. Don't be rude :). Bty Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The button listener works now, but my condition doesn't, if i write something in the edit text, it doesn't go inside the else, it just calls the if toast and nothing else happens... so weird

Comment: Could you please debug and check? In open eye it's impossible.

Comment: It is not getting what i write inside the edit text, it is always " ". That's why it doesn't go inside the else part.

Comment: `done` button click working? which one causing problem? or both?

Comment: Also could you please update your code which you trying now?

Comment: `done` button is working yes, when i click `enviar` button it doesn't get what i wrote in the edit text to pass it in the comentario variable.

Comment: That's mean both `enviar` click not dismiss dialog and shows toast right?

Comment: Almost, if i do not write anything inside the edit text and click the button, it dismisses and shows the toast, if i write something, it shows the toast, if i erase what i wrote and click it again, it only shows the toast as well, it only dismisses the dialog if i don't use the edit text in any way and just click the button.

Comment: What a strange things it is? :(

Comment: Big relief :D. It's my pleasure to help you. You are also welcome.